# How to use ForEach to create TextFields from an array?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to construct a form from an array of fields

```
class Field : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var label : String
    var value : String

    init(label: String, value: String) {
        self.label = label
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

```
class App: ObservableObject {
@Published var fields : [Field] = [
    Field(label: "PV", value: "100"),
    Field(label: "FV", value: "0"  )]

    func update(label: String) {
        switch label {
            case "PV" : fields[0].value = calcPV()
            case "FV" : fields[1].value = calcFV()
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use a `ForEach` iterator in the View.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: App
        
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(app.fields) { field in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: { self.app.update(label: field.label) } ) {Text(field.label)}
                    TextField("0", text: field.value)  // error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code results in the error message `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'` where I try to pass `field.value` into `TextField()`.

I haven't been able to find a way to create a `Binding` to pass to `TextField()`.

I can get the wanted behaviour by explicitly calling `TextField("0", text: self.$app.fields[1].value)` but want to be able to do this with the `ForEach` so that I can construct a generic form from an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for such case:

```
ForEach(Array(app.fields.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { i, field in
    HStack {
        Button(action: { self.app.update(label: field.label) } ) {Text(field.label)}
        TextField("0", text: self.$app.fields[i].value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi.  That achieves what I wanted.  For my specific case I can make the problem a bit simpler if I set an explicit id for the fields, which I post as a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer looks like a good general solution.  For the specific case, it can be solved by setting an integer `id` for each `Field` that corresponds to the position in the array.

```
class Field :  Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let id : Int
    var label : String
    var value : String
    
    ...
```

```
class App: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fields : [Field] = [
        Field(id: 0, label: "PV", value: "100"),
        Field(id: 1, label: "FV", value: "0" )
    ]
    ...
```

Then this `id` can be used in the `TextField` parameters:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: App
        
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(app.fields) { field in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: { self.app.update(label: field.label) } ) {Text(field.label)}
                    TextField("0", text: self.$app.fields[field.id].value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```